# Doesn't work regular expression for domain with hyphens

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sh

I have some smart script, that check name of server and get domain name. For example, i have name of server: example.ru01. I need to get: example.ru My scipt:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname=example.com01
echo $hostname
reg0="\(\(\w*\.[a-z]*\)\|\(\w*\.[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\)\)"
domain=`expr match $hostname $reg0`
echo $domain
```

It is ok. in output i have:

```
example.com01
example.com
```

But, in my infrastructure, i have some domains with hyphens. For example: test-test.com01. But it doesn't working in my script. How to resolve this problem ? Please help. I made some changes in my regular expression, like this:

```
\(\(\w*\.[a-z_-]*\)\|\(\w*\.[a-z_-]*\.[a-z_-]*\)\)
```

But it doesn't work. Where i have error ? Please help. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the `01`?

Comment: I don't think you can have domain names with underscores `_`

Comment: Try `reg0="\w*\([.-]\w*\)\+"` or `reg0="\w\+\([.-]\w\+\)\+"`

Comment: The 'get domain name' requirement is unclear. It's not clear how `example.com01` maps to `example.com` other than the removal of trailing digits. Are you simply wanting to remove any trailing digits or is there a more thorough requirement that you can describe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `test-test.com01` will not match.

However, `www.test-test.com01` will:

```
$ hostname="www.test-test.com01"
$ reg0="\(\(\w*\.[a-z_-]*\)\|\(\w*\.[a-z_-]*\.[a-z_-]*\)\)"
$ expr match $hostname $reg0
www.test-test.com
```

The problem is that you are requiring an optional `w` (zero or more times) **and a dot `\.`**.

Well, in fact, what you wrote is "a word"  `\w`, in this case you should remove the backslash if what you want to match is the "www".

Also, underscores are incorrect in a domain name. This is the correct regex that you should use:

```
reg0="\(\(w\{1,3\}\.\)\?[a-z-]\+\(\.[a-z-]*\)\?\)"
```

In this one, the `www.` is matched optionally and then one or (optionally) two names with a dot in between.

However, domain names could include numbers:  `www.1and1.com`

And, in fact, Watch out !!  now they could contain any valid UTF-8 string:

From section 3.3 of [RFC 6531](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531):

> The definition of  is extended to permit both the RFC
> 5321 definition and a UTF-8 string in a DNS label that conforms
> with IDNA definitions [RFC5890].

And section 2.3.2.1 of [RFC 5890](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5890#section-2.3.2.1)

> A "U-label" is an IDNA-valid string of Unicode characters, in
> Normalization Form C (NFC) and including at least one non-ASCII
> character, expressed in a standard Unicode Encoding Form (such as
> UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, the little problem that you had is that you added `-` to the part of Regex that is responsible for matching the last part of the domain such as `.com`, `.net` or `.ru`. Instead, you should add `-` to the first part of regex. This should work:

```
req0="\(\(\[a-z0-9_-]*\.[a-z]*\)\|\([a-z0-9_-]*\.[a-z0-9_-]*\.[a-z]*\)\)"
```

This regex `[a-z0-9_]` can be shortened using this token `\w`, and it works without any problem. However, this token `\w` does not seem to function inside `[]` in bash, therefore, I used `[a-z0-9_]` in order to add `-` .